# What size pool jets am I supposed to purchase for 1.5 inch pipes?

Tags: pool, measuring

In my pool, I have two white PVC pipes that push water out, where jets are supposed to fit to increase flow rate.

The diameter of these pipes is 1.5 inches.

I purchased a 5-pack of "Pool and Spa Eyeball Jet 1.5" Threaded to 3/4" Open" jets from an online retailer.

I was sent a pack of 5 jets where the diameter of the threaded portion measured 1.75 inches, too big to fit in the 1.5" wall pipes.

I returned the pack, and requested the correct size.

Again, I was sent the same 1.75 inch pack back.  The product is a Pooline item number 11211C.  I found [an independent description](https://www.discountpoolmart.com/product_info.php/pool-spa-hot-tub-jets/pooline-hydrostream-jet-thread-opening-11211c-p-5626) which measures the threaded portion as *1-1/2" MIPT*.

Below is a photo from the website referenced above showing the MIPT, and photos of the items I received with a tape showing measurement.

Before I return these items for a third time, I want to make sure I am purchasing for the correct width.  **Am I simply being sent the wrong item, or am I asking for the wrong item?  If so, what should I be asking for?**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nominal pipe size is for the hole on the inside of the pipe, and that is still subject to "nominal"

A pipe which is 1-1/2 inches (actually 1.557) on the outside is a **1-1/4" pipe.**

A 1-1/2 inch pipe is 1.796 inches OD.

[Here's a handy and very detailed chart/diagram](http://machiningproducts.com/html/NPT-Thread-Dimensions.html)

You have been asking for the wrong part, and have been sent the part you asked for, twice.

Answer (score 0):

In my admittedly non-plumber experience, you're being sent the correct item, you simply don't have the correct adapter. You need to get a 1.5" slip to 1.5" FPT adapter - they should be commonly available at your local big-box home improvement retailer in the plumbing section. The slip side goes on the source pipe - you can ask the store personnel about how to glue it on (it's almost ridiculously simple) and what glue you need. Take the nozzles you have with you as a CYA to make sure the adapter fits snugly when screwing them together - in the final isntallation, you may need an O-ring or thread tape of some form.

Comment: But why is the 1.5" threaded end actually 1.75" in diameter? It is much bigger than the pipe it is supposed to thread into.

Comment: It's a "standard" size measurement, not an "actual" size measurement. Very similar to the way the actual size of a "2x4" is 1.5 by 3.5 inches.

Comment: So what standard size measurement should I be purchasing if I want to fit the interior of a 1.5 inch threaded tube?

Comment: Male or female threaded end? Honestly - go talk to the plumbing department at your local big-box home improvement retailer. You're overthinking things.

Comment: The pipe in my pool is a 1.5 inch female threaded so I tried to purchase a 1.5 inch male threaded to go into it but I keep getting sent 1.75 inch male is there something I'm missing as to why when I request the 1.5 inch male I get 1.75 inch multiple times?

Comment: Do not measure it with a ruler or measuring tape. A 1.5 inch threaded pipe is not 1.5 inches in diameter. The "1.5 inches" is a trade size, not an actual size. Go talk to a plumbing person at your local big-box home improvement store or a local plumber.

Comment: I just finished restoring my pool and had the same issue...was about to order the eyeballs and noted only 1.5 inch threaded were offered. But the thread diameter of the old fitting for my pool cleaner (which I saved) is 1.75 inch. After investigating and taking pain reliever for headache, I found the above responses to be accurate. The 1.5 inch threaded pipe takes an eyeball which is 1.75 inch diameter threads. I am still trying to find out why a 2x4 is not 2x4 when I am paying for a 2x4 !

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have threads, you can use what is called an "insider" or "Aussie insider" which fits smooth into the actual pipe without a female threaded adapter. They come in sizes for 1 1/2" or 2" pipe.